# Angular2 HashLocationStrategy and SEO

Tags: angularjs, angular, seo

I have an Angular 2 app which is at [www.tilecase.com](http://www.tilecase.com)
I'm wondering about SEOand the HashLocationStrategy used by the router.

If I input urls with a # into the Google url register it says that the urls are not valid, hence I guess that Google doesn't index them in any case.

I want to index urls such as https://www.tilecase.com/#/forBusiness

How can I get my urls indexed? I've read about Angular Universal. Is that the main strategy people are using?

Also why does Angular 2 use HashLocationStrategy? Isn't this an older way of doing urls and well defined routes separated by / favoured now?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Comment: Yes, Angular Universal all the way. It may be possible to do this [with HTML5 mode alone, at least for Google](http://react-etc.net/entry/does-googlebot-render-angular-2-without-angular-universal).

Comment: @Ben Cameron How do you fix this issue on your website.?